# Java XML to EDI design

Tags: java, xml, freemarker, edi

I have a requirement to convert XML to EDI. I have searched a lot for open source free libraries which full fill my need, but could not find any.

So I decided to write my own logic.

Below are my requirements for an application I am going to execute.

**Input of the application is**: XML data

**Output of the application is**: EDI (Electronic Data Interchange) representation of the XML data.

I have to apply some business rules on XML data and generate the EDI representation.

Here is my design for the requirement:

- The Java POJOs, here onwards these are Source POJOs, to represent the xml data. To load xml data into Source POJOs, I am using JAXB.
- The Java POJOs, here onwards these are Target POJOs, to represent the EDI model.
- A Java class, here onwards it is XmlToEDIBuilder, to code the business rules
- Finally I am using FreeMarker Template to get the desired EDI structure out of Target POJOs.

Is my design looks good? Any suggestions would really help me.

Comment: I don't think FreeMarker handles EDI very well.  There's a reason EDI libraries aren't free.  No one wants to maintain the standards in their app for free.  You should be looking at a mapper like MapForce or Contivo that generates Java code if you need to embed.  Or you should look at another EDI mapper as a scalable, standalone solution.

Comment: @Ram, So what did you end up doing. I have a same requirement where I have to convert XML to EDI 834. Would be very helpful if you could share some insights here

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had a project involving edifact parsing and generation. 
I used http://www.smooks.org/ framework for that purpose.

Using the framework mentioned above your application logic steps might be the following:

- parse XML to POJO
- use precompiled smooks components and your POJO to build your desired edifact version

Smooks components could be extended in case some custom and/or client specific edifact format needed.

Here is the usage example to get you started: https://github.com/lunatech-labs/smooks-examples/blob/master/edifact-in-code-manipulation/src/main/java/example/Main.java